# An anti-concentration inequality?

Tags: probability, inequality

Prove or disprove the following:
$$ \exists K>0 \; \forall \epsilon_0 (>0, \leq 1) \; \exists \epsilon (>0, \leq \epsilon_0) \;  \exists p (p>0, \; p\leq \frac{1}{2}, \; \frac{\epsilon}{p} \geq 2, \; \frac{\epsilon}{p} \in \mathbb{Z} ) \; [(1-p)^{\frac{\epsilon}{p}} + \epsilon (1-p)^{\frac{\epsilon}{p} - 1} \leq 1 - K\epsilon \;] $$

My attempt at proving it: 
Take an arbitrary $0<p\leq \frac{1}{2}$, $ 0<\epsilon \leq 1 $ satisfying $\frac{\epsilon}{p} \geq 2$

\begin{aligned}
(1-p) &\leq e^{-p}\\
\implies (1-p)^{\frac{\epsilon}{p}} &\leq e^{-\epsilon}\\
(1-p)^{\frac{\epsilon}{p} - 1} &\leq e^{-\epsilon}.e^{p}\\
\implies \epsilon (1-p)^{\frac{\epsilon}{p} - 1} &\leq \epsilon.e^{-\epsilon}.e^{p}\\
\therefore (1-p)^{\frac{\epsilon}{p}} + \epsilon (1-p)^{\frac{\epsilon}{p} - 1} &\leq e^{-\epsilon} + \epsilon.e^{-\epsilon}.e^{p}\\
&\leq e^{-\epsilon}(1 + \epsilon.e^{p}) \\
&\leq (1-\frac{\epsilon}{2})(1 + \epsilon.e^{p})\; \text{( Since}\; \forall x \in [0,1]\; (e^{-x} \leq 1-\frac{x}{2})\;)\\ 
&\leq K(1 - \frac{\epsilon}{2}) \; \text{( Where}\; K\; \text{is an absolute constant > 1; since} \;\epsilon\; \text{and}\; p\; \text{are bounded)}
\end{aligned}

Edit:
The claim is equivalent to the following one -

$$ \exists K>0 \; \forall \epsilon_0 (>0, \leq 1) \; \exists \epsilon (>0, \leq \epsilon_0) \;  \exists p (p>0, \; p\leq \frac{1}{2}, \; \frac{\epsilon}{p} \geq 2, \; \frac{\epsilon}{p} \in \mathbb{Z} ) \; \forall f\; (f \sim Binomial(\frac{\epsilon}{p},p)) \; [Pr [f\leq1] \leq 1 - K\epsilon \;] $$

Answer (score 1):

The claim is true. It follows from Hoeffding bound.

Take  $K=1,\; \text{aribtrary } \epsilon_0 \leq 1, \; \epsilon = \min(\frac{1}{2},\epsilon_0), \; p  = \frac{\epsilon^2}{8} (\leq \frac{1}{32})$

Now,
\begin{aligned}
\Pr[\;f \geq 2\;] &= \Pr[\;f \geq (p + \frac{2p}{\epsilon}-p)(\frac{\epsilon}{p})]\\
&\geq e^{-2(\frac{2p}{\epsilon}-p)^2(\frac{\epsilon}{p})}\\
&\geq e^{-2(\frac{2p}{\epsilon})^2(\frac{\epsilon}{p})}\\
&= e^{-\frac{8p}{\epsilon}} \\
&\geq 1 - \frac{8p}{\epsilon} \\
&= 1 - \epsilon\\
&\geq \epsilon \\
\end{aligned}

$\therefore \Pr[\;f\leq 1\;] \; \leq\; 1 - \epsilon$ , as required.

Helpful reference: https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=3712